# Jinja2 concatenate string to get values to input

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to read a dict  to put values in a jinja2 template:

```
 answers = {'obs_18': None, 'obs_1': 'jack', 'rot3': None, 'obs_4': None, 'rot10': None, 'obs_8': None, 'rot7': None, 'rot6': None, 'rot13': None, 'rot21': None, 'obs_13': None, 'rot9': None, 'rot20': None, 'rot11': None, 'obs_7': None, 'rot17': None, 'obs_9': None, 'obs_21': None, 'obs_11': None, 'rot12': None, 'obs_19': None, 'obs_20': None, 'rot16': None, 'rot1': None, 'obs_10': None, 'rot15': None, 'rot18': None, '_id': ObjectId('5ad4b9a7f1ccd84582282207'), 'obs_16': None, 'obs_15': None, 'rot22': None, 'rot19': None, 'rot4': None, 'obs_5': None, 'rot5': None, 'obs_6': None, 'rot8': None, 'obs_12': None, 'obs_14': None, 'rot14': None, 'obs_17': None, 'rot2': None, 'obs_2': None, 'obs_22': None, 'obs_3': None}
```

using loop.index to populate a form with default values for input fields as strings, but the values shown are just as strings, like:

```
answers['obs_1']
```

, instead of the correct value '**jack**'.

i'm using this:

```
<input id="obs_{{ loop.index}}" name="obs_{{ loop.index }}" cols="30" rows="2" value="answers['obs_{{ loop.index }}']"></input>
```

The values are displayed if i use:

```
{{ answers }}
```

Any clues?

Passing args:

```
@app.route('/checklist/<string:_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def checklist(_id):
    form = CheckList()
    perguntas = mongo.db.perguntas.find()
    n_perguntas = mongo.db.perguntas.count()
    print(n_perguntas)
    perguntas.sort([('id',1)])
    answers = mongo.db.checklists.find_one_or_404({'_id':ObjectId(_id)})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for k in range(1,n_perguntas+1):
            st = str(k)
            answers.append({"rot"+st: request.form.get('rot'+st), "obs_"+st: request.form.get('obs_'+st)})
        print(answers)
    return render_template('checklist.html', form=form, perguntas=perguntas, answers=answers, logeduser=session['username'])
```

template:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %} 
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h2 style="margin-top: 50px;"><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Check-list 912 {{ answers['_id']}} </h2>
    <!-- <form action="/checklist" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.f1.label }} {{ form.f1(class="form-control form-control-md") }}

        </div>
    </form> -->
    <form action="/checklist/{{ answers['_id']}}" role='form' method="POST">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>N.O.</th>
                <th>Pergunta</th>
                <th>Dispositivo</th>
                <th>Resultado</th>
                <th>Observação</th>
            </tr>
            {% for p in perguntas %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{ loop.index }} </td>
                <td> {{ p.pergunta }} </td>
                <td> {{ p.dispo }} </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <input name="rot{{loop.index}}" type="radio" value="1">Sim</input>
                        <br>
                        <input name="rot{{loop.index}}" type="radio" value="2">Não</input>
                        <br>
                        <input name="rot{{loop.index}}" type="radio" value="3">S/I</input>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="obs_{{ loop.index}}" name="obs_{{ loop.index }}" value="answers['obs_{{ loop.index }}']"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor%}
        </table>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
   {{ answers }}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Look carefully into `value="answers['obs_{{ loop.index }}']"`. That is exactly your output. You are just evaluating the index part of the string.

Comment: I think you should do instead: `value={{ answers['obs_{{ loop.index }}'] }}`

Comment: Didn't work out Iron Fist

Comment: Are u passing `answers` to your template?, can you post more code as how you are passing this variable to the rendering function?

Comment: There is the edit with the route.

Comment: Can u also post more code for your `checklist.html` template?

Comment: I see that in your template you are looping through `perguntas` and using its `loop.index` you try to access `answers` values, Can you try to print into the console( `print(perguntas);print(answers)`) the content of both variable and post them into your question here?

Comment: The set of 'perguntas' is not really relevant. The set of 'answers' was already given in the question post.

Comment: The same values shown for 'answers' set are printed in the console.

Comment: @DavidBorges, I just wanted to make sure that this is a looping index issue, so you have to make sure that the right `loop.index` is passing right value to you `answers`, try to use this filter to check if `answers` is having right `loop.index` to build your key: `value={{ answers['obs_{{ loop.index }}'] | default('loop.index was wrong') }}`

Comment: Also remember that `loop.index` is 1-based indexing while `loop.index0` is 0-based indexing in Jinja2

Comment: Now shows 'loop.index' in the input field. Seems not defined but the string was cut. Doesn't show 'loop.index was wrong'

Comment: loop.index is used in the first td of table starting with '1'.

Comment: Alright, may be try with : `value={{ answers.get('obs_'+loop.index) }}` ?

Comment: Almost: this worked. value={{ answers.get('obs_'+loop.index|string) }} . But this was very close.

Comment: What do you mean by *very close* ?

Comment: It complained that could not convert int to string. Your answer is right! Thank you!

Comment: Alright, Glad it worked out at the end :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, the issue was passing a variable within another one, so, the right way to do it was:

```
value={{ answers.get('obs_' + loop.index | string) }}
```

Comment: It seems like you have an extra `)`